# oracle: select information about a function/procedure

Tags: oracle, function, database-schema, procedures

I would like to retrieve information about procedures/functions from **Oracle** database. I know, that I can use `ALL_PROCEDURES` and `USER_OBJECTS` tables, but they only inform me about names of existing procedures/functions. I would like to get return type and argument without parsing any source. Is that possible under **Oracle**? It's pretty easy under **PostgreSQL** and can be done under MySQL (argument under 5.5 AFAIK).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want the `ALL_ARGUMENTS` view (or `USER_ARGUMENTS` or `DBA_ARGUMENTS`)

```
SQL> create or replace function f1( p_in in varchar2,
  2                                 p_in_out in out number )
  3    return number
  4  is
  5  begin
  6    return 1;
  7  end;
  8  /

Function created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  select argument_name, position, in_out, data_type
  2    from all_arguments
  3   where object_name = 'F1'
  4*    and package_name is null
SQL> /

ARGUMENT_N   POSITION IN_OUT    DATA_TYPE
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
P_IN_OUT            2 IN/OUT    NUMBER
P_IN                1 IN        VARCHAR2
                    0 OUT       NUMBER
```

Comment: The SQL*Plus `describe` command also works for procedures, functions, and packages.